# Is there a lodash function to wait for a condition?

Tags: node.js, lodash

I'm using an API which provides an async method used like this:

```
api.isActive(function(err, active) {
    // check for error
    // use active boolean
});
```

The underlying object state is "volatile", i.e. it changes without any interaction from the program.

I'd like to wait for a given state - this will involve calling isActive repeatedly (with some interval) until the desired state is determined. The entire operation should be given a maximum amount of time for the state to be achieved before bailing out. An old-school nodejs `callback(err)` should be called with the completion (this can be promise-ified later).

I could write some code with `setTimeout()` but I'd prefer to use a canned solution or pattern, and lodash seems likely to provide something but I can't quite see what method could be used for this.

Comment: based on the docs, it doesn't look like it, https://lodash.com/docs

Comment: Have you looked into using [`q`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) or [`bluebird`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird)?

Answer (score 1):

lodash doesn't have such function, cause it's can be done with `setInterval` easily

if you want some **wait** logic, try to look on
https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor

but, anyway, you need to use `setInterval` / `setTimeout` for checks